# MS-DOS Bear/Teddy Bear Spooky Halloween game?

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-game

In about 1993-4 I played a (probably free or shareware) MS-DOS game about a bear/teddy bear entering a house which was "spooky", I believe related to Halloween. Graphically it was primitive, somewhat at the level of Mixed Up Mother Goose (1986) and the audio was so bad as to be nearly if not totally unintelligible on that computer. The gameplay was roughly point-and-click Sierra Adventure-like: one was able, as a bear, to move around in a house and click on various objects to interact with them. I couldn't find this game in the entire recorded catalogues of Sierra or Apogee, nor on any of the "abandonware" sites including the DOS repository on Archive.org. It was probably developed and produced from the mid-to-late '80s or early '90s, probably roughly a range from 1984-1993.

Any ideas what this game is?

Comment: Could it have been https://www.mobygames.com/game/fatty-bears-birthday-surprise/screenshots?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it was more primitive and less funny :)

Comment: I have been trying to find a game too and i think it may be the same one. Sorry i cant provide the name but maybe more details would help? I was born in '92 and it was my dad's computer. I remember in order to access the game I had to type "BEAR" into a command line or something when the computer was booting up, and then it would take me to the game. The only things I remember for sure are that there was a bear and a pumpkin patch, and a party at the end that you only see from outside a window. I don't think there was color. Just black background and grey pixels. I'm not sure if this is the ca